# YII LDAP connection for user authentication

Tags: yii, ldap, yii-extensions

I am new to yii frame work I am trying to create an ldap configuration for user authentication 
The following steps which I taken to create but it throws eerro as below

include(Controller.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

C:\xampp\htdocs\yiif\framework\YiiBase.php(418)

steps:
1. I have included the following ldaprecord/ 
extension in C:\xampp\htdocs\seed2\protected\extensions\ldaprecord
2. I have included the following code in config/main.php

```
`'components'=>array(
'user'=>array(
// enable cookie-based authentication
'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
),
'ldap'=>array(
'class' => 'ext.ldaprecord.LdapComponent',
'server' => 'ldap://192.168.x.xxxx',
'port' => 389,
//'bind_rdn' => 'cn=suren diran,cn=Users,dc=xxxx,dc=demo,dc=com',
//'bind_pwd' => 'pass@123',
'base_dn' => 'dc=rsales,dc=demo,dc=com'),);
'params'=>array(
// this is used in contact page
'adminEmail'=>'sundarapandian@rsalesarm.com',
),
'ldap'=>array(
'class' => 'ext.ldaprecord.LdapComponent',
'server' => 'ldap://192.168.x.xxx',
'port' => 389,
//'bind_rdn' => 'cn=xxxx xxxx,cn=Users,dc=xxxx,dc=demo,dc=com',
//'bind_pwd' => 'pass@123',
'base_dn' => 'dc=xxxxx,dc=demo,dc=com'),
);`
```

1. included this line in the index.php

   `$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/extensions/ldaprecord/CLdapRecord.php';`
2. and I have changed the useridentity authentication function as

`
    public function authenticate()
    {
    $username=$this->username;
    $password=$this->password;
    $dname= 'xxxxxxx';
    $options['host']='ldap://192.168.x.xxx';
    $options['port']=389;
    $ldap_username = "CN=".$username.",CN=Users,DC=xxxx,DC=demo,DC=com";

```
$options = Yii::app()->params['ldap'];
print_r($options);
$connection = ldap_connect($options['host'], $options['port']);

//print_r($connection);
ldap_set_option($connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

if($connection)
{
echo "success";
//exit;
try
{
//echo $connection.$ldap_username.$this->password;
//print_r(ldap_bind($connection,$dname."\\". $ldap_username, $password));
//exit;
@$bind = ldap_bind($connection,$dname."\\". $ldap_username, $password);
print_r(@$bind);
if(@$bind)
{
echo "successfully logedin";
}
}
catch (Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage();
}
if(!$bind) $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
else $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
}
return !$this->errorCode;
};`
```

I am stucked here can any one help me hw to resolve this issue .please help me ,Thanks in advance..........

controller.php file was exists in the protected/components 
even I check that it was included in the main .php

```
'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'ext.ldaprecord.*',
    ),
```

if I remove the following line the following error will shown 
code:

```
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/extensions/ldaprecord/CLdapRecord.php'
```

error:
Property "CWebApplication.ldap" is not defined.

yes I am using that extension only which u given link above([http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ldaprecord/]),if u have any other extension please can u provide that link and what the steps need to be taken for that to implement .........thanks in advance..........

HIIIIII

I done mistake in the params now I have changed that as below , and I removed the

```
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/extensions/ldaprecord/CLdapRecord.php';
```

it was not throwing any error .

I am including the my main.php full code below:

```
<?php
   return array(
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'..',
    'name'=>'xxxxxx',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        //ldap config added code
         'ext.ldaprecord.*',

    ),

    'defaultController' => 'site/login',

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii'=>array(
            'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'=>'pass',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
        ),

    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(
        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),

        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format

        /*'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),*/

            /*'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:'.dirname(__FILE__).'/../data/testdrive.db',
        ),*/
        // uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxxx',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'tablePrefix' => '',
        ),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),



        'ldap'=>array(
            'class' => 'ext.ldaprecord.LdapComponent',
            'server' => 'ldap://192.168.x.xxx',
            'port' => 389,
            //'bind_rdn' => 'cn=suren diran,cn=Users,dc=xxxxxx,dc=demo,dc=com',
            //'bind_pwd' => 'pass@123',
            'base_dn' => 'dc=xxxxx,dc=demo,dc=com'),




    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'xxx@xxxx.com',
        'ldap'=>array(
            'class' => 'ext.ldaprecord.LdapComponent',
            'server' => 'ldap://192.168.x.xxx',
            'port' => 389,
            //'bind_rdn' => 'cn=suren diran,cn=Users,dc=xxxxx,dc=demo,dc=com',
            //'bind_pwd' => 'pass@123',
            'base_dn' => 'dc=xxxx,dc=demo,dc=com'),
    ),

);
```

I am including my useridentity function below:

```
<?php
 public function authenticate()

{
        $options = Yii::app()->params['ldap'];
        //print_r($options);
        $connection = ldap_connect($options['host'], $options['port']);
        ldap_set_option($connection, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
        ldap_set_option($connection, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

        if($connection)
        {
           // try
          //  {
                //echo $options['domain']."\\".$this->username. $this->password;
                //exit;
                $ldap_username = "CN=".$this->username.",CN=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=demo,DC=com";

        $ldap_password=$this->password;
        echo $connection.$ldap_username.$ldap_password;
        //$bind=ldap_bind($connection, $ldap_username, $ldap_password)
                //exit;
                //print_r(ldap_bind($connection,$ldap_username,$ldap_password));
                $bind = @ldap_bind($connection,$ldap_username, $ldap_password);
                print_r($bind);
                //exit;
           //@$bind = ldap_bind($connection,$ldap_username, $ldap_password);
            //   $abc=@$bind;
               //print_r($abc);

               //exit;
            /*}
            catch (Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }*/
            if(!$bind) $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
            else $this->errorCode = self::ERROR_NONE;
        }
        return !$this->errorCode;
}
```

But in the above one the ldap_bind is not working can u help on this ........
Please help me I how to overcome this .........thanks alot.....

Answer (score 1):

I've just been reading this:

```
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/extensions/ldaprecord/CLdapRecord.php'
```

Why have you done that? I assume you're using [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ldaprecord/) extension: It doesn't advise anywhere in thedocumentation to do so. This is pretty much emptying your application's config - including the `import`-stanza which is ultimately letting the include of the `Controller.php` fail.

Comment: yes i am using that extension only which u given link above,if u have any other extension please can u provide that link and what the steps need to be taken for that to implement .........thanks in advance..........

Comment: Not thrashing your config were a start. And check for the nesting levels of the brackets in your config. Something is pushing the `ldap`-part out of the `components`-stanza.

Comment: 'components'=>array(
'errorHandler'=>array(
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),
  'log'=>array(
   'class'=>'CLogRouter',
   'routes'=>array(
    array(
     'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
     'levels'=>'error, warning',
    ),
       
   ),
  ),
  
  
  
  'ldap'=>array(
            'class' => 'ext.ldaprecord.LdapComponent',
            'server' => 'ldap://192.168.x.xxxx',
            'port' => 389,
            //'bind_rdn' => 'cn=xxxx xxxx,cn=Users,dc=xxxx,dc=demo,dc=com',
            //'bind_pwd' => 'pass@123',
            'base_dn' => 'dc=xxxxx,dc=demo,dc=com'),
  
  
  
  
 ),

Comment: @$bind = ldap_bind($connection, $options['domain']."\\".$this->username, $this->password);    is not working can u say what will be the error on my end

Comment: This is horribly to work with. Can you please confirm your components stanza looks roughly like [this](https://gist.github.com/DaSourcerer/e5ebd88c027197c88392)? If so, I can't see why Yii would error out stating there were no `CWebApplication.ldap` attribute. Also: 'is not working' is too little of an information to work with. Sadly, the original author of this extension also chose to halt the application via `die()`instead of throwing exceptions, whcih is making debugging incredibly hard ...

Comment: Hi thanks alot please can u say any another way to create an ldap user authentication in yii .........or please help me to over come this error

Comment: I'm afraid not. I don't have a LDAP setup at hand and you are not providing enough informations to sufficiently help you.

Comment: can u say the what the information need from my end for sufficiently helping me ....

Comment: For starters, stop saying things like "this doesn't work." Quoting an error message would help tremendously. Not sure if I can really help you any further though as my own experience with LDAP is quite limited.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for another extension I would point you to [this blog post](http://www.exchangecore.com/blog/yii-active-directory-useridentity-login-authentication/). It's not an extension but is fairly detailed on how to set it up and looks like it will accomplish the same end goal for you.